# Tracking pixel dimensions of 0 useful?

Tags: tracking

Not discussing the good and bad of tracking pixels here, I wonder whether it is ok to set `width` and `height` of a tracking pixel to `0` each?

All examples and usages I see use a value of `1` for these, so I wonder if there is any reason for it?

I just quickly tried it in Chrome and saw that indeed, an image with `width` and `height` set to `0` is requested by the browser, despite not being rendered.
Maybe there are browsers out there that would not send a request to `0`-dimensioned images and this is the reason why all examples use `1` pixel?

Could anyone enlighten me here?

Comment: https://www.gmass.co/blog/tracking-pixel-blockers/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it obviously is ok to use a value of `0` für tracking pixel `width` and `heihgt`. There are examples out there that use these values.

Pro: You can skip CSS for hiding these pixels.